# determine largest bit encoding in huffman

Tags: compression, huffman-code

Very simple question but I cant seem to find the answer to it. Given a Huffman table of X size is there any equation to quickly determine the number of bits of the least frequent character in the table?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get an upper bound given the probability of the least frequent symbol, using the Fibonacci sequence. See [this paper](http://www.work.caltech.edu/pub/Abu-Mostafa2000Huffman.pdf).

You can of course directly calculate the length of the longest code quite quickly using Huffman's algorithm.